# Keep users logged in for 9hours until click logout

Tags: php, session, logout

I am facing an issue with my script in Godaddy shared hosting. users gets logged out randomly,

can someone help fix my code to keep users logged in for at least 9hours without losing session once logged in?

i have tried numerous ways like increasing the session.gc.lifetime through php.ini and also htaccess but still users are getting logout out randomly.

here is my login execution php code

```
include('password.php');
class User extends Password{

    private $_db;

    function __construct($db){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_db = $db;
    }

    private function get_user_hash($username){

        try {
            $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT member_id, employee_id, password, username, level, team FROM crm_members WHERE username = :username ');
            $stmt->execute(array('username' => $username));

            return $stmt->fetch();

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
        }
    }

    public function login($username,$password){

        $row = $this->get_user_hash($username);

        if($this->password_verify($password,$row['password']) == 1){

            $_SESSION['crm_loggedIn'] = true;
            $_SESSION['crm_member_id'] = $row['member_id'];
            $_SESSION['crm_employee_id'] = $row['employee_id'];
            $_SESSION['crm_username'] = $row['username'];
            $_SESSION['crm_level'] = $row['level'];
            $_SESSION['crm_team'] = $row['team'];
            
            return true;            
        }
    }

    public function crm_logout(){   
        session_destroy();
    }

    public function is_logged_in(){
        if(isset($_SESSION['crm_loggedIn']) && $_SESSION['crm_loggedIn'] == true){
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

and this bit of code i put in every pages for check if user is logged in

```
if(!$user->is_logged_in()){ header('Location: login.php'); }
```

and this is for logout.php

```
$user->crm_logout();
```

Will really be thankful if you could help me out with my above codes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Would this suffice? <b>ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 32400);</b> // Server Keeps session for 9 hours That is 3600 x 9 and <b>session_set_cookie_params(32400);</b> // Client remembers session for 9 hours That is 3600 x 9 See this documentation here https://www.codeleaks.io/increase-session-timeout-in-php/

Comment: @Joseph thanks aton this was exactly what i needed

Comment: Glad to have helped. I added it as the answer to the question here below.

Answer (score 0):

See if the below helps.

In your PHP add the following;

```
<?php

// Server Keeps session for 32400 seconds which is actually 9 hours. That is 3600 x 9
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 32400);

// Client remembers session for 32400 seconds which is actually 9 hours. That is 3600 x 9 
session_set_cookie_params(32400); 

?>
```

See this documentation here for your reference https://www.codeleaks.io/increase-session-timeout-in-php/